# How to update user Profile textfields and profile photo same time on Android Using Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I'am using Retrofit 2.I'am trying to implement "PATCH" method to updating profile photo on main thread.I also tried on Postman.I can update the profile photo.

### [PATCH request success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGkIQ.png)

This is my interface when I use calls.Also UpdateUser is the model w

```
 @PATCH("user/{username}/")
Call<User> updateUserProfile(@Path("username") String username, @Body UpdateUser User);
```

---

This is my User Model

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;

@SerializedName("first_name")
@Expose
private String firstName;

@SerializedName("last_name")
@Expose
private String lastName;

@SerializedName("profile_photo")
@Expose
private String profilePhoto;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getProfilePhoto() {
    return profilePhoto;
}

public void setProfilePhoto(String profilePhoto) {
    this.profilePhoto = profilePhoto;
}
```

---

This is my ProfileUpdatePresenter I handle request here

```
   public class ProfileUpdatePresenter
  {
  private ProfileUpdateView profileView;
  private ApiInterface apiInterface =           
  MyAPIClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

  public ProfileUpdatePresenter(ProfileUpdateView profileView) {
    this.profileView = profileView;
  }
```

I get user on this method

```
public void getUserProfile(Activity activity, String username) {
    apiInterface.getUserProfile(username).enqueue(new CustomCallBack<User>(activity) {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Response<User> response) {
            super.onResponse(call,response);
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                profileView.onProfileGet(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            super.onFailure(call,t);
        }
    });
}
```

---

I update User here

```
 public void updateUserProfile(Activity activity, String Username, UpdateUser User){
    apiInterface.updateUserProfile(Username,User).enqueue(new CustomCallBack<User>(activity) {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Response<User> response) {
            super.onResponse(call,response);
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                profileView.onUpdateSucceed(response.body());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            super.onFailure(call,t);

        }
    });
```

---

On my UpdateProfile Activity.I get the user by implementing My presenter's methods.Then also I update here.But I'am confused on how to update my profile photo here.

```
 @Override
public void onProfileGet(@NotNull User user) {
    UserProfile = user;
    if(UserProfile.getFirstName() != null)
        et_name.setText(UserProfile.getFirstName());
    if(UserProfile.getLastName() != null)
        et_surname.setText(UserProfile.getLastName());
    if(UserProfile.getPhone() != null)
 }
```

---

I also use interface to implement methods that I use on main thread

```
public interface ProfileUpdateView {
void onProfileGet(@NotNull User user);
void onUpdateSucceed(@NotNull User user);
```

}

---

To be honest The main Problem for me is how to Use My Old @PATCH for updating the profile photo.Basically How to combine these on one Call?

```
@PATCH("user/{username}/")
Call<User> updateUserProfile(@Path("username") String username, @Body UpdateUser User);
   + 
@Multipart
@PATCH("/retrofit_tutorial/retrofit_client.php")
Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("file") RequestBody name);
```

Comment: Can you try PATCH method with @Multipart just like in POST method.

Comment: @ChetakBhimani I edited the code.The thing is how to approach the patch method combining the default one with multipart.

Comment: @ChetakBhimani also can I update profile photo with updateUserProfile ?

Comment: @ChetakBhimani my aim is sending in one request.Thank you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify server's API to **@POST + Multipart** then you can do following:

```
@Multipart
@POST("user/{username}/")
Call<User> updateUserProfile(
        @Path("username") String username,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part photo,
        @Part("json_user") String jsonUser
);

// Some Utils for request
public MultipartBody.Part fileToPart(File file) {
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
            "photo", // param name
            file.getName(),
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file)
    );
}

// usage 
updateUserProfile("Dude", fileToPart(myFile), new Gson().toJson(myUpdateUser))
```

Comment: Can you please explain more please.What changes should api  must have.Can't I done without changes

Comment: For example server might handle **@GET("user/{username}/")**  and **@POST("user/{username}/")** as two different requests as well as **@PATCH**. I mean you should contact with your backend developer and discuss about request format.